# Are we wrong in feeling alienated by gender-specific clubs organizing company-wide events?

Tags: human-resources, discrimination, gender

The company I work for recently sent out a company-wide invitation for an annual, upcoming **STEM Day** which includes workshops, prizes, speakers, and more - all around the theme of STEM (science, technology, engineering and mathematics). The invitation closely reads:

> The Women of STEM & Friends Network is celebrating our third annual STEM Day... This event is to celebrate and elevate [STEM] work that goes on daily at [company]. The Women of STEM & Friends are organizing this event in partnership with the Women of Digital & Friends, Women of Merchandising & Friends, and Women of [department] & Friends networks.

Many colleagues and I feel alienated (or in the case of the women, condescended) from this company-wide event by the fact that it's organized by groups that are clearly meant for one gender. We feel further validated in this sentiment when the email further reads:

> - Dress For Success Clothing Drive: ... some of the highest needs are for unused cosmetics and toiletries for their onsite salon are shampoo, conditioner, toothbrush & toothpaste, feminine products and miscellaneous makup (eyeliner, lipstick, and foundation)

and **thirteen of the fourteen guest speakers are women**.

If you visit the various chat channels of the groups organizing the event, there is little-to-no activity by males and the rooms are full of "women do it better" kind of chatter. Some of us are at a point where we feel gas-lit by the rhetoric that "Women & Friends" means "everybody", but then why not just call it the "Everybody STEM Club"?

We're not advocating for the disbandment of a women's STEM group, but we feel there is a conflict of interest when said group is organizing the  company-wide STEM Day, is using that day to promote a clothing drive clearly geared for women, and having 13 of 14 speakers be female. Are these fair sentiments? Is this even something HR cares about?

Comment: Do you feel alienated because you don't believe in the cause or because you're not a woman?  I have male colleagues (I'm male btw) who turn up to women in STEM events often, and they've never experienced anything other than a warm welcome.

Comment: From my experience as a computing professional starting in 1970, and as a mathematics student at Imperial College London before that, I can assure that attending an event with few, if any, speakers of one's own gender is a survivable experience.

Comment: They focused on women for education in science and maths in the UK and have recently found they left the males behind...

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I think this is not about the gender of the speakers, but about publicly showing favor and making provision for one gender above another.

Comment: @ig-dev I assumed from the speaker gender ratio being the only bold text that it was somehow troubling the OP.

Comment: One's sentiments are not always fair or logical. No one can dispute your sentiments. Are you required to attend this event? If not, I wouldn't worry about it. I suppose you could always organize your own competing STEM event for next year/next quarter, but honestly, is this something that you feel that strongly about enough to want to organize something?

Comment: Do you have any other STEAM day celebration organized? Or is that only that "The Women of STEM" organized such event at your company?

Comment: To understand what they're doing, you have to first understand that women are underrepresented in STEM, and the women who are in STEM face subtle (and often overt) challenges because of it. They're responding by providing extra support for women in every way they can, not for the purpose of bringing them up above men, but for the purpose of overcoming those extra challenges women face. To say, "but what about men?" would be to dismiss those challenges, and that's an option, and to attend as a friend would be to acknowledge them and show support, or learn a little more.

Answer (score 11):

I am a woman in STEM, although I don't belong to any 'women in STEM' organisations. Before going into gender issues - you have to ask yourself if there was any non-gendered group that was interested in organising your STEM day? If your company said "someone do this" and only the Women of STEM & Friends agreed then that's what you want to change. Are there any active gender neutral organisations in your workplace? Are you a member of any that you feel should be represented?

Below are some more general points from your questions.

> we feel gas-lit by the rhetoric that "Women & Friends" means "everybody", but then why not just call it the "Everybody STEM Club"

Because "women and friends" means just that. It doesn't mean all men. Some men aren't friends to women. Some men are openly hostile or dismissive. Most men are normal, rational, people and so they're welcome. However, putting "men and women" is not the same as "this is a space for people who aren't dreadful to women".

Also, why would women's groups want to hide what they are? They want the women in the company to feel like the event is for them. Now, from what you've said they might be failing but that doesn't mean there were bad intentions. Also, just because some women have said it's weird/ silly doesn't mean they actually believe that or that those women represent all women.

> there is a conflict of interest when said group is organizing the company-wide STEM Day, is using that day to promote a clothing drive clearly geared for women

That hasn't been said. They are highlighting items that are needed. Generally, anyone can fit into a pair of trousers or shirt. They might not be a great fit but they'll get you through a job interview alright. But for women makeup is expected in interviews, and sanitary products are a basic need. Both are more specialist and more easy to forget about when donating. Highlighting this is not saying not to donate other items. Either way, adding a reminder about a donation drive doesn't seem bad. It's not mandatory and no one will know who did/didn't donate, right?

> having 13 of 14 speakers be female.

This is only valid if you've ever been concerned when 13 out of 14 speakers were men. How many male and female speakers were there in your STEM days in years 1 and 2? Does making this set of speakers almost all women mean there's 50/50 representation of the genders over the years? Or at least the same split of genders as in STEM in your region?

Of course a mix would be better but if those 13 women have something of note to say then why can't they all say it? Of course the female-geared organisations will know great female speakers. If you want more male speakers, suggest some. Or volunteer to speak yourself.

> Are these fair sentiments?

Yes and no. It's fair to feel pushed out when a group doesn't include you. However, that's what being a woman in STEM has been like for decades (and more). Trying to help more people join a group often starts like this. It starts with more labels and more groups that will all merge together once everyone's accepted.

"When you’re accustomed to privilege, equality feels like oppression"

This strikes me like the man I used to work with. Another woman organised a "national women's day party" (just some baked goods in the kitchen to grab if you wanted). He complained that there wasn't a "national men's day" and then, when it was pointed out that there was one, he complained that she'd not organised something for it.

> Is this even something HR cares about?

I highly doubt it.

Comment: *sanitary products are a basic need* And an **extremely** common request by charities. OP should expect to see that one come up again if the company later does a drive for a homeless shelter or something similar.

Comment: "When you’re accustomed to privilege, equality feels like oppression"
This feels like a pretty off-topic remark. The problem here is very different, in what way would this situation be exercising equality? if the same exact event occurred but swap for man every mention of woman, it would not be acceptable anywhere I know.

Fighting for extra privileges for women is not fighting for equality. Fighting for equality means fighting for more father rights the same way you fight the wage gap. To fight for more women in plumbing and welding the same way you fight for more women in tech.

Comment: -1. I am pretty sure you wouldn't say that the following is okay: `It doesn't mean all men. Some men aren't friends to women. Some men are openly hostile or dismissive. Most men are normal, rational, people and so they're welcome. However, putting "men and women" is not the same as "this is a space for people who aren't dreadful to women".` if we swapped woman for man. Then it would be awful and not acceptable, why the same but for women seem okay for you to say?

Comment: @H4uZ Since if we take all the male speakers at STEM events (I'd guess even just at OP's company) and add 13 women to the other side then we are still nowhere near approaching equal representation. All female panels are fine. As are all male panels. *As long as everyone gets represented.* The best way would be to have equal representation of all genders and races in all events but that's sometimes impossible and not everyone is welcoming. So, some minority/ disadvantaged groups will do their own events. That's not oppression. It's making a place to grow towards equality.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul - yes, that seems reasonable. If we were discussing male victims of abuse or male nurses then a similar sentiment would apply. That was not the question asked.

Comment: You could be learning a lot from this moment. The next time you see a conference with 13 men out of 14 speakers, you could remember this feeling and understand how the women who work with you feel at those conferences. Really soak in these feelings of "this is not for me, they are excluding me" and then compare them to the logical statements ("it says 'and friends', that can be you") rebutting them. When the shoe is back on the other foot where it normally is, you may be more understanding of how your women and nonbinary colleagues feel most of the time.

Comment: @coaoalo You've presented it as if there is nothing wrong there, and that's just wrong. Not a subject to debate, but just as saying "all men are welcome, and some women" is not acceptable, neither is the reverse. It's not a matter of controversial debate, or doubt, it's very simple discrimination and as such not acceptable.

Comment: @KateGregory I don't remember discriminating anyone in my entire life, so what other foot are you talking about? And I will tell you another deeply hidden secret, neither did the majority of the men you will ever meet in your life. Would you like to hear your own commend as a response to your complaint against discrimination? I doubt that very much, so don't.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I never said you discriminated. The shoe will be on the other foot when 13 of 14 speakers are men, the "dress for success" seminar is for men, the recruiting pictures are all men, and so on. You don't see that today. You think it's balanced. Experiencing a lack of balance can be illustrative and useful. You feel excluded even though nobody has said "stay away men!" Can this teach you how women feel experiencing the normal setup in STEM?

Comment: @KateGregory What do you assume that I need to be taught that, and that I don't know that without this "amazing lesson" in discrimination?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul nobody who understands how women in STEM feel under normal circumstances would "ask" a long rant about how exlusionary, gaslighty, and general unfair it is to have an event aimed at women.That said, the amount of effort I'm willing to expend on this has now been reached. Take care!

Comment: @KateGregory Actually, I just did, but it seems that the idea of someone being against discrimination, to the point where this offends it and also having male genitalia doesn't fit into your world view. Not to mention someone with male genitalia understanding it, the gull! Which is sad, very sad.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul almost all events put some conditions on their attendees. Some events mandate particular clothing (e.g. swimsuits), others expect certain activities (e.g. you're there to play football), and some events have criteria on behaviour (e.g. don't shout during the opera). Every work function has these criteria too. Coworkers need to be respectful and civil as a minimum. Anyone who can't do this at a work function shouldn't be there. I would say the same thing about women bashing men (e.g. OP's "women do it better").

Answer (score 2):

> Are we wrong in feeling alienated by gender-specific clubs organizing company-wide events?

To select is to deflect. Favoring one gender is disfavoring the other.

Whether this is morally acceptable in this case depends on your personal and political views. Some see sexual discrimination against men in a different light as discrimination against women. This becomes apparent in common dictionary definitions of "sex discrimination":

Cambridge Dictionary:

> treatment of men and women differently, **especially unfair treatment of women**

Merriam Webster:

> discrimination based on sex and **especially against women**

So according to common definitions women have a special position in regard to this form of discrimination. Some views will tolerate favorable treatment of women (as you are experiencing) but not of men. To demonstrate this, imagine this was a "Men's event" with explicitly "male-only speakers", advertising provision of male hygiene products, and the expectation of, as you say, `men do it better` chatter. This would remove all ambiguity.

> Are these fair sentiments?

This is something that you have to decide for yourself, and a highly controversial topic. StackExchange is the wrong platform for to make conclusive statements about which view is correct.

Regarding the subjective question if you are "wrong by *feeling* alienated", I believe this can be objectively answered with "no", since the invitation is especially geared towards women. Any invitation that does not fully embrace the recipient in equal terms may understandably give an alienating impression.

> Is this even something HR cares about?

Assuming the email does not legally constitute an act of discrimination in your country, this depends strongly on the political views of the leadership and the resulting company policies. There may or not be laws surrounding this issue in your country.